# I'm getting jquery errors

Tags: jquery, code-cleanup

I can't get this to work, and don't understand where the error would be

```
(function(){



        jQuery(window).bind('scrollstart', function(){
            $('header').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    // Animation complete
                  });                
        });

        jQuery(window).bind('scrollstop', function(e){
            $('header')..fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    // Animation complete
                  });
         });

    })();
```

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please specify your title and question. What exactly does not work?

Comment: two periods? Which do I get ride of?

Comment: it helps to specify the exact error.  Don't just say "I'm getting errors", or "it isn't working."  You need to be precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `$('header').fadeIn('slow', function()`

not `$('header')..fadeIn('slow', function()`